# Help me find the id of a part - two clips back-to-back

Tags: part-identification

Help me find the id of this LEGO part please!

[image: two clips back-to-back]

Comment: Hi c1oz7 and welcome to Bricks.SE! Please take the time to read the [tour] and the [help] pages to learn the local customs which will let you write great questions.

Answer (score 7):

This is definitely not a LEGO part, but one from a compatible brand. Looks like a [Brickarms U-Clip](http://www.brickarms.com/U-clip.php).

Comment: Can you tell me where I can buy?

Comment: If you click on the link provided, there is literally a section on that page labeled "where to buy."